# Ubuntu not loading into GUI

Tags: 22.04, gui

I turned on my laptop (not dual boot) and the only thing that loads is the terminal. I guess that the GUI didn't load. I used neofetch and the details are correct. What do I have to do, in order to get into the GUI? Did I accidentally uninstalled it? Please send help (beginner btw)

Some info from neofetch:

Kernel: 5.15.0-47-generic
Packages: 2143 (dpkg), 16 (snap)

Comment: what happens if you type "startx"? What GPU do you have? Did you install the correct graphics drivers?

Comment: Hey @Esther. Found a post from 2013 in the forums, and I had to just reinstall the ubuntu-desktop app and restart. All good now.

Comment: You  may answer your own question and if it gets an upvote, accept it after a few days, helping others and gaining some reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```